# how to add group by values in a column in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which is as following

```
   **ip                  page                date                 page_Views
127.0.0.1              index.php           2012-07-09              25
182.445.11.1           abc.php             2012-07-09              11
116.142.24.7           index.php           2012-07-09              3
```

I want to extract the page_views column grouped by page

that mean for 'index.php' it show page_view = 28

I'm using this query

SELECT * FROM `stats_tracker` GROUP BY `page`  ORDER BY `stats_tracker`.`page_views` DESC

using this query i am grouping the page_views according to page but not adding so

page_views for index.php =25 according to my above query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the SUM aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  ip,
  page,
  CONCAT(MIN(date), " - ", MAX(date)) as date_range,
  SUM(page_views) as total_page_views
FROM stats_tracker
GROUP BY page
ORDER BY total_page_views DESC
```

The basic reasoning is that MySQL doesn't know *how* you want to combine values when you group. Sometimes you want to count, sometimes sum, and even averaging is available. Check out [the MySQL Aggregate Functions page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Note my treatment of the dates, since they will also lose their meaning without some aggregate function applied there as well.

Comment: It is giving following error Notice: Check your MySQL select query, it might have problems

Comment: The syntax may be off on the dates handling. I have taken that out for now. Let me know how you want to use the date info.

Comment: date is not issu. i want sum of page_views according to page

Comment: I know it's not what you want, I mean the dates section of my original query may have had problems, so I removed that part. Is the current query in my question working? And if not, can you paste in the exact error?

Comment: Aha, @PugganSe got it... I had totally overlooked the FROM clause. :-/

Comment: problem!   you did not put table name in the query why?

Comment: Why? heh... simple error. Sorry for the confusion. User Puggan Se edited my answer to include it, thanks to Puggan Se.